# Execute drive cleanup command for remote server powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the below code for cleaning space in C drive. It is working fine locally but I have to execute it for remote servers

```
$ProcessInfo = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "$env:SystemRoot\system32\dism.exe"
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "/Online /NoRestart /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup"
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $true
$ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Minimized
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
$Process.Start() | Out-Null
```

Please let me know how to execute this for remote server using Invoke-command or some other way

Comment: use `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: How to use these multiple lines under invoke-command

Comment: It's pretty straight forward: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { code here } -ComputerName RemoteComputer`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1), will definitely help later on down the road. Can also use `Get-Help Invoke-Command`.